# How to restrict resourceful routes in Laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel

I want to create some resourcesful routes but yet restrict some methods so they don't show up as routes.

This could be such a resourceful route:

```
Route::resource('users', 'UsersController');
```

And I remember there was a method to restrict these resourceful routes like this:

```
Route::resource('users', ['uses' => 'UsersController', 'except' => ['store', 'delete']]);
```

Yet when I do something like this I get an

**[ErrorException] Array to string conversion**

How do I restrict resourcesful routes in Laravel 5, without typing each route manually?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using the wrong syntax.

```
Route::resource('users', 'UsersController', [
    'except' => ['store', 'delete']
]);
```

It is very clear [in the docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/controllers#restful-resource-controllers) under **Customizing Resource Routes**.

Comment: Yes, you are right about the docs. I just didn't find it by googling and thought that maybe someone else will google this too, and the redundand answer on stackoverflow might help him find the solution more quickly. Thank you for your contribution.

Comment: I rejected your edit request, because I believe the title represents the long-tail-keyword which other people might use to solve this problem